# Проблема с вызовом функции из dll для Python

Tags: python

Я  собрал dll для программы на Python. Вот код экспортируемой функции:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "PollSensors.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

__declspec( dllexport ) double __GetLightSensor();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

double __GetLightSensor()
{
    Sensor sensor;

    if (!sensor.is_available()) { return 1; }

    sensor.poll();
    Sleep(250);
    return sensor.get()[0];
}
```

Это библиотека для получения данных от датчика света в Windows. Думаю, не стоит приводить код класса Sensor, собранная в exe программа успешно работает и печатает данные в консоль. Но во беда с загрузкой этой dll в Python:

```
from ctypes import *

lib = windll.LoadLibrary("lightSensor.dll")

while True:  
    print lib.__GetLightSensor()

Всегда выводит только одно значение.... Несмотря на то, что данные, выводимые данной функцией меняются в зависимости от степени освещения. Что я не правильно делаю?
```

Comment: А что там в doc'ах-то написано?

     15.17.1.8. Return types

     By default functions are assumed to return the C int type. Other return types can be specified by setting the restype attribute of the function object.

Comment: Имеется в виду ctypes.c_double? Это тоже не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, разобрался.
from ctypes import *

```
lib = windll.LoadLibrary("lightSensor.dll")
lib.__GetLightSensor.restype = c_double

while True:  
    print c_double(lib.__GetLightSensor())
```

Comment: @Xyanight а что значит 

      print c_double(lib.__GetLightSensor())

возможно лучше 

      print lib.__GetLightSensor().value()